# $.post in jquery is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My `$.post` is not working as I am  trying to extract JSON data from my PHP file, I don't know the reason why it's not showing the output?
Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<pre id="love" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="mymodal(\''+this["id"]+'\')">'+this["love"]+' students <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg" style="color:red"></i></pre >
```

where `this["id"]` has been passed to `mymodal()` function.

javascript code:

```
var list='';
    function mymodal(id){
    $.post('postname_.php',{post_id:id},function(data1){
    $.each(data1.result,function(){
    list+='<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">'+'<div class="modal-dialog">'+'<div class="modal-content">'+
    '<div class="modal-header">'+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>'+
    '<h4 class="modal-title">Students who loved your post</h4>'+' </div>'+'<div class="modal-body">';
    list+='<h4 class="text-danger">'+this["finame"]+' '+this['sename']+'</h4>';
    list+='</div>'+'<div class="modal-footer">'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+'</div>'+
    '</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>';
    $('#insert').append(list);}),'json'
    });
    }
```

my php code:

```
<?php
require("../vendor/library50-php-5/CS50/CS50.php");
CS50::init(__DIR__ . "/../config.json");

    $result=array();
     $frows3=CS50::query("SELECT * FROM userhit WHERE plove=? AND bypost=?",1,$_POST['post_id']);
     foreach($frows3 as $frow3){
      $frow4=CS50::query("SELECT * FROM userinfopersonal WHERE user_id=? ",$frow3['user_id']); 
     $frow5=CS50::query("SELECT * FROM userprof WHERE user_id=? ",$frow3['user_id']); 
     array_push($result,array('finame'=>$frow4[0]['firstname'],'sename'=>$frow4[0]['secondname'],'url1'=>$frow5[0]['url']));

     }echo json_encode(array('result'=> $result)); ?>
```

where CS50::query  provides me all my rows of table which  satisfy the given query, no worry about that, I checked that's giving perfect json file. The main problem is the `alert` in function `mymodal()` is working that means on clicking pre tag it's coming inside function, but the alert inside `$.post` is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `'json'` argument for `$.post()` function is not within the correct function scope. See the updated code below (I took the liberty of removing the excess string concatenation – I may be wrong, but it didn't appear to have utility). Proper spacing can help to catch these syntax errors.

```
var list='';
function mymodal (id) {
    $.post('postname_.php', {post_id: id}, function (data) {
        $.each(data.results, function (i, result) {
            list+='<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Students who loved your post</h4></div><div class="modal-body">';
            list+='<h4 class="text-danger">' + result["finame"] + ' ' + result['sename'] + '</h4>';
            list+='</div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div></div></div>';
            $('#insert').append(list);
        });
    }, 'json');
}
```

To see the difference, here is the original code tabbed in a more conventional manner.

```
var list='';
function mymodal(id){
    $.post('postname_.php',{post_id:id},function(data1){
        $.each(data1.result,function(){
            list+='<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">'+'<div class="modal-dialog">'+'<div class="modal-content">'+
            '<div class="modal-header">'+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>'+
            '<h4 class="modal-title">Students who loved your post</h4>'+' </div>'+'<div class="modal-body">';
            list+='<h4 class="text-danger">'+this["finame"]+' '+this['sename']+'</h4>';
            list+='</div>'+'<div class="modal-footer">'+
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+'</div>'+
            '</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>';
            $('#insert').append(list);
        }),'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: yup that was a mistake ,yeah now alert is working fine,but still `list` is not appending to `#insert`

Comment: Try using `$('#insert').html(list);` See: http://api.jquery.com/Html/ for more details.

Comment: Looking closer, `$.append()` should work. Does the `#insert` element already exist in the DOM tree when this code runs?

Comment: actuall yes it does exist

Comment: Try passing the parameters explicitly to the callback function for `$.each()`. I updated the code above to illustrate this. Note: I guessed the accessors for the response object, so they may not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is correct (*Please format the code before asking for help in online forums*).
https://jsfiddle.net/s295zzmt/

Your HTML code looks in correct, probably because it was copy pasted from within JavaScript code. But since you said that `alert` inside `mymodal` function is working correctly, lets ignore it.

There are two possibilities.

1. The HTTP request is failing
2. It is returning invalid JSON

Check network tab in Firefox Developer Tools / Chrome Developer Console. Make sure that the XHR request is returning `200 OK`. If so, check the HTTP response and ensure that it is valid JSON.